# How to distinguish faked SAML Response?

Tags: saml-2.0, spring-saml, opensaml

I have a HTTP POST servlet to receive SAML response and decode the response, then get the email from response. Suppose my IDP endpoint is https://myIdp.com. Following is an response example:

```
<samlp:Response xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" ID="_8e8dc5f69a98cc4c1ff3427e5ce34606fd672f91e6" Version="2.0" IssueInstant="2014-07-17T01:01:48Z" Destination="http://sp.example.com/demo1/index.php?acs" InResponseTo="ONELOGIN_4fee3b046395c4e751011e97f8900b5273d56685">
  <saml:Issuer>http://idp.example.com/metadata.php</saml:Issuer>
  <samlp:Status>
    <samlp:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success"/>
  </samlp:Status>
  <saml:Assertion xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" ID="pfx0e02f9bf-9d08-14ab-b927-4ab9b979e46b" Version="2.0" IssueInstant="2014-07-17T01:01:48Z">
    <saml:Issuer>http://idp.example.com/metadata.php</saml:Issuer><ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
  <ds:SignedInfo><ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
    <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
  <ds:Reference URI="#pfx0e02f9bf-9d08-14ab-b927-4ab9b979e46b"><ds:Transforms><ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/><ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/></ds:Transforms><ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/><ds:DigestValue>ckLpItzLtCvyEpzIMpBoOB4HQdU=</ds:DigestValue></ds:Reference></ds:SignedInfo><ds:SignatureValue>VPa3SbxN6EzHKb3qg4Q8nh3eGok9rwifeZ3QPn784zOEqxxJcqttI8unOHiQJRjf5fepBvuWegPqAWSWi3vlAlSyHfVdofF1hthJJdDY94mT9jIc9rMKhm1zpn5b1LE3Pl6Bg0AMUlN7ajZP5v3lLSJPuGEAaptdQFHc1j5m0sU=</ds:SignatureValue>
<ds:KeyInfo><ds:X509Data><ds:X509Certificate>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</ds:X509Certificate></ds:X509Data></ds:KeyInfo></ds:Signature>
    <saml:Subject>
      <saml:NameID SPNameQualifier="http://sp.example.com/demo1/metadata.php" Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient">_ce3d2948b4cf20146dee0a0b3dd6f69b6cf86f62d7</saml:NameID>
      <saml:SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer">
        <saml:SubjectConfirmationData NotOnOrAfter="2024-01-18T06:21:48Z" Recipient="http://sp.example.com/demo1/index.php?acs" InResponseTo="ONELOGIN_4fee3b046395c4e751011e97f8900b5273d56685"/>
      </saml:SubjectConfirmation>
    </saml:Subject>
    <saml:Conditions NotBefore="2014-07-17T01:01:18Z" NotOnOrAfter="2024-01-18T06:21:48Z">
      <saml:AudienceRestriction>
        <saml:Audience>http://sp.example.com/demo1/metadata.php</saml:Audience>
      </saml:AudienceRestriction>
    </saml:Conditions>
    <saml:AuthnStatement AuthnInstant="2014-07-17T01:01:48Z" SessionNotOnOrAfter="2024-07-17T09:01:48Z" SessionIndex="_be9967abd904ddcae3c0eb4189adbe3f71e327cf93">
      <saml:AuthnContext>
        <saml:AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:Password</saml:AuthnContextClassRef>
      </saml:AuthnContext>
    </saml:AuthnStatement>
    <saml:AttributeStatement>
      <saml:Attribute Name="uid" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic">
        <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">test</saml:AttributeValue>
      </saml:Attribute>
      <saml:Attribute Name="mail" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic">
        <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">kliu@myIdp.com</saml:AttributeValue>
      </saml:Attribute>
    </saml:AttributeStatement>
  </saml:Assertion>
</samlp:Response>
```

If someone knows the format of the response, he can use some post tools such as PostMan to send a post request to my SP post servlet. For example, he replaces the following attribute:

```
 <saml:Attribute Name="mail" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic">
        <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">kliu.fake@myIdp.com</saml:AttributeValue>
      </saml:Attribute>
```

This request is not from myIdp.com. But my servlet could not validate if it is from myIdp.com. Is there a way to deny the fake request?

There is  and I can get the signature using OpenSAML. I found some people using following code, but how to get the publicKey then get the publicCredential?

```
try {
            BasicX509Credential publicCredential = new BasicX509Credential();
            publicCredential.setPublicKey(publicKey);
            SignatureValidator signatureValidator = new SignatureValidator(publicCredential);
            signatureValidator.validate(signature);
        } catch (ValidationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
           // throw new InvalidAssertionException("Assertion signature validation failed.");
        }
```

Comment: saml assertions should be signed by the issuer -- look in the <ds:SignatureValue> element. The issuer should provide you with the cert with which you can verify the signature. The cert is often included in the response anyway, in the  <ds:X509Certificate> element, but it should be exchanged independently beforehand. If you are unable to verify the signature, then you can be suspicious that the assertion has been tampered with and you can deny the request.

Comment: There is  <ds:X509Certificate> and I can get the signature using OpenSAML, however, how to get the publicKey then get the publicCredential?

Comment: since you will have the cert ahead of time, check out getPublicKey()
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/cert/Certificate.html